# How to load several different release apk for different countries in Google Play Market?

Tags: android, apk, release

We need to include different functionalities in different countries, and we can not target this based on the device language, it's necessary to target it to the countries.
Preparing for an application for each country is a bad idea

Comment: release different apk for different country :) You need different package name for each country.

Answer (score 0):

Do not release multiple apk files for different countries. As you said it's a bad idea. Instead you can use different languages in you single app. This is called "Localization".

There are many tutorials available for the same.

Go ahead and try it.

Comment: Localization by language is not suitable. For example, in Russia and Belarus one language of devices, but different functionality is needed for these countries